# Create a title for each column on a table using a loop. JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want the title for each column on a table to be'A','B','C' etc, I want to be able to change how many columns there are so I want to use a loop.
Code so far:

JavaScript:

```
<script>
document.getElementById('dtable').innerHTML = '';
var table = document.getElementById("dtable")
Rows = 4
for (var count = 0; count <= Rows; count++) {
    var header = table.createTHead(0);
    var row = header.insertRow(0); 
    var character = String.fromCharCode(65 + count);
    var cell = row.insertCell(count);
    cell.innerHTML =('<b>'+character+'</b>');
}
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<div id='div1'><table id="dtable"></table></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You were creating one row in the header for each column.
Moving the thead creation outside the loop fixed it.

```js
document.getElementById('dtable').innerHTML = '';
var table = document.getElementById("dtable");
var header = table.createTHead(0);
var row = header.insertRow(0); 
Rows = 4
for (var count = 0; count <= Rows; count++) {
    var character = String.fromCharCode(65 + count);
    var cell = row.insertCell(count);
    cell.innerHTML =('<b>'+character+'</b>');
}
```

```html
<div id='div1'><table id="dtable"></table></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to create a new row inside of the loop right? Move the head and row creation outside of the loop.

like:

```
<script>
document.getElementById('dtable').innerHTML = '';
var table = document.getElementById("dtable")
Rows = 4
var header = table.createTHead(0);
var row = header.insertRow(0); 
for (var count = 0; count <= Rows; count++) { 
    var character = String.fromCharCode(65 + count);
    var cell = row.insertCell(count);
    cell.innerHTML =('<b>'+character+'</b>');
}
</script>
```

If you want it to look like a table with borders and such you'll have to add css styling but that should print a b c d e

Answer (score 0):

@Dilly,
 Use this fiddle... As many other answers for the post -  you need to create a row once and columns as many times as you wish... so loop for columns not rows. Which also reminds me to tell you - *Please don't use loop count variable name as "Row" that is point of confusion. You should name it - numOfColumns for example.*

Thanks to the comment, I added this commentary.

https://jsfiddle.net/shemdani/xjpekb94/1/

```
document.getElementById('dtable').innerHTML = '';
var table = document.getElementById("dtable")
var row = table.insertRow(0); 
Rows = 4
for (var count = 0; count < Rows; count++) {
    var character = String.fromCharCode(65 + count);
    var cell = row.insertCell(count);
    cell.innerHTML =('<b>'+character+'</b>');
}
```

Comment: Why? Code-only answers are typically not very useful to future users

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are creating the header and the row inside your `for` loop, which means that you will be creating a new row each time, which causes problems with `row.insertCell`. The first iteration works because you are inserting a cell in the 0th position, but the second iteration of the loop attempts to insert a cell in the 1st position, when a 0th position cell does not exist, hence why it throws an error. Try this and it should work for you:

```js
document.getElementById('dtable').innerHTML = '';
var table = document.getElementById("dtable");
var Rows = 4;
var header = table.createTHead(0);
var row = header.insertRow(0); 

for (var count = 0; count <= Rows; count++) {
    var character = String.fromCharCode(65 + count);
    var cell = row.insertCell(count);
    cell.innerHTML =('<b>'+character+'</b>');
}
```

```html
<div id='div1'><table id="dtable"></table></div>
```